# How to write a numpy array to a csv file?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, python-3.4

I want to open up a new text file and then save the numpy array to the file. I wrote this bit of code:

```
foo = np.array([1,2,3])
abc = open('file'+'_2', 'w')
np.savetxt(abc, foo, delimiter=",")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-fea41927952b> in <module>()
      2 model = cool
      3 abc = open('file'+'_2', 'w')
----> 4 np.savetxt(abc, foo, delimiter=",")

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt,     delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments)
   1071         else:
   1072             for row in X:
-> 1073                 fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
   1074         if len(footer) > 0:
   1075             footer = footer.replace('\n', '\n' + comments)

TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Additionally, I found an empty file created in the terminal called file_2, but nothing is written inside it.

EDIT: I am using Python3.4

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Also, no need to `'file' + '_2'` -- that's just making the computer work to generate something you could hard code: `'file_2'`.

Comment: works fine for me, you  must be using python3

Comment: Yea I'm using python3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears you are using Python3. Therefore, open the file in binary mode (`wb`), not text mode (`w`):

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.array([1,2,3])
with open('file'+'_2', 'wb') as abc:
    np.savetxt(abc, foo, delimiter=",")
```

Also, close the filehandle, `abc`, to ensure everything is written to disk. You can do that by using a [`with`-statement](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211102/http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) (as shown above).

As DSM points out, usually when you use `np.savetxt` you will not want to write anything else to the file, since doing so could interfere with using `np.loadtxt` later. So instead of using a filehandle, it may be easier to simply pass the name of the file as the first argument to `np.savetxt`:

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.array([1,2,3])
np.savetxt('file_2', foo, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Unless you're appending to a preexisting file, I'm not sure there's much reason to pass a handle.  Might as well just pass `"file_2"` as the first argument to `savetxt`, no?