# live sensor reading store in a data file

Tags: python, numpy

i have a acceleration sensor which continuously outputs reading in 400 Hz ( like `[0.21511 0.1451 0.2122]` ). I want to store them and post process them. Now im able to store the first entry of the reading not all.

How to make it happen.

thanks

```
from altimu10v5.lsm6ds33 import LSM6DS33
from time import sleep
import numpy as np

lsm6ds33 = LSM6DS33()
lsm6ds33.enable()

accel=lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces()

while True:


    DataOut = np.column_stack(accel)
    np.savetxt('output.dat',np.expand_dims(accel, axis=0),  fmt='%2.2f %2.2f %2.2f') 

sleep(1)
```

´

Comment: Welcome to SO, What is the actual issue you are facing ?

Comment: now i got the real problme. Just move this line into While loop : `accel=lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces()`  please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual  problem is, You are calling `get_accelerometer_g_forces()` only once. 
Just move it inside While looop

Updated:

```
while True:
    accel=lsm6ds33.get_accelerometer_g_forces()
    f=open('output.dat','ab')
    DataOut = np.column_stack(accel)
    np.savetxt(f,np.expand_dims(accel, axis=0),  fmt='%2.2f %2.2f %2.2f') 

sleep(1)
```

Here is a reference :[How to write a numpy array to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659814/how-to-write-a-numpy-array-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Closing the file fro time to time and appending it would be a good idea ineed, especially since there is not exit condition

Comment: hi.
result of this code returns same reading again and again in many times in data file.
i want live changing readings like that .

Comment: @user508402 - yup and  yours is more python way

Comment: gracious ,  @user508402

Comment: gracious @Backtrack

Comment: `import calender
import time
ts = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
` 

hei how can i add timestamp in this row.

`np.savetxt(f,np.expand_dims(accel, axis=0),  fmt='%2.2f %2.2f %2.2f') `

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that reading the data is enclosed within to loop!

You don't need numpy here yet:

```
while True:
    with open("output.dat", "w") as f:
        f.write("%.5f, %.5f, %.5f" % tuple(accelerometer_g_forces()))
```

Note that there is no condition to stop outputting the data.